# IOS- NSNotificationCenter- notify specific instance

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using NSNotificationCenter, the listener subscribe with the following code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(editRSSLAbel:)
                                             name:@"editLabel"
                                           object:nil];
```

And the sender sends the notification with this posting:

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"http://www.nba.com" forKey:@"link"];                                               

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"editLabel" object:self userInfo:dataDict];
```

But, i want to notify a specifit viewController **instance**, and with the above machinisem i don't have the ebility to do so.

Any idea will be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesnt support this directly, you can register to this notifications with your App, not with your view, the os not familiar with your internal implementation, so you can add a dictionary with a name of the controller and hold a dictionary of names-controllers to forward it to the right view

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new key with a tag in that data dictionary you are posting. In all of the view controllers that receive the notification check that tag to see if matches "their" tag is so then they can process the data or they can simply return from the method.